# how to get name of streams from a big string using php?

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all

i got a big string that holds list of streams. i managed to get the stream urls but now i want to get stream names( name1, name2, name 3) so i can use them later to construct the hyperlinks. could any one show me how i can get the stream names?

```
    preg_match_all("@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@", $file_contents, $foo); 
    print_r($foo[1]);

  for($i = 0; $i < count($foo[1]); $i++){
             echo $foo[1][$i]."<br>" ; 
    }//end of for
```

example of big string that holds list of stream($file_contents):

```
name1 http://somesite.net/all/name1tv.m3u8
name2 http://somesite.net/all/name2tv.m3u8
name3 http://somesite.net/all/name3tv.m3u8
```

Comment: Are you wanting to get results like `name1, name2, name3`? Are all the names consisting of only alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Thanks for reply .i want each stream name  as variable so i can use them in construction hyperlinks (using that variable as name of each hyperlink) . yes i want to get name1,name2,name3 which is at start of each line .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'll want to split your big string into an array of lines so that you can process each line and extract the data you want.

You can do this by using `explode()` and a `\n` as the delimiter:

```
$stream_array = explode( '\n', $big_stream_string );
```

Now what you'll want to do is iterate over the array and use `explode()` with a space character as the delimiter - this will split each line into two parts - the first part is the name and the second part is the rest of the line:

```
$names = array();
foreach( $stream_array as $stream ){
  $split = explode( $stream, " " );
  array_push( $names, $split[ 0 ] )
}
```

Your `$names` array should now be populated with the stream names.

Comment: thanks but where should i construct the hyperlink so i could refrence both stream url and stream name ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand. This is not what your original question was asking.

Comment: so there no way to separate stream name from stream url and create hyperlinks? i already got the url but only want to get corresponding stream name before i create hyperlinks but don't know to to get the stream names! i tried following but names doesnt print from array!  could you help me fix it?  for($i = 0; $i < count($foo[1]); $i++){

?>

<a href="./doit.php?ID=<?php  echo $foo[1][$i] ; ?>&title= <?php echo $names[0][$i] ;?>"><?php echo $i.") "; echo $names[0][$i] ;?> </a> <br />

<?


}//end of for